# Make azure-pipelines.yml environment specific

Tags: azure, pipeline, environment

How can I write azure-pipelines.yml to be environment specific.
For now in my angular application , I have one big azure-pipelines.yml which has all the stages defined : deploy_to_dev, deploy_to_sit etc.
I want to break down this azure-pipelines.yml into environment specific like azure-pipelines-dev.yml , azure-pipelines-sit.yml.
How can I do this and trigger the corresponding pilelie.yml file.